# Technical Term for choosing distribution of starting point of a time series in a way such that the time series is stationary

Tags: time-series, terminology, stationarity, autoregressive

In Time Series Analysis there is this idea of choosing the distribution of the starting point of a time series in a way such that the time series is stationary. Let for example $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^T%$ be a time series following an AR(1) process ($X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t, \ \varepsilon_t \sim wn(0, \sigma^2)$). The Wold(-like) decomposition looks like this:
\begin{align}
X_t = X_0 + \sum_{i = 0}^{t-1} \phi^{i} \varepsilon_{t-i} 
\end{align}
Relevant for the stationarity is e.g. the variance which is given as
\begin{align}
Var(X_t) = Var(X_0) + \sigma^2 \sum_{i = 0}^{t-1} \phi^{2i} = Var(X_0) + \sigma^2 \frac{1 - (\phi^2)^{t}}{1 - \phi^2}. 
\end{align}
Now in order for $X_t$ to be stationary, we have to choose $X_0$ in such a way that
\begin{align}
Var(X_0) = \sigma^2 \sum_{j = t}^{\infty} \phi^{2j}
\end{align}
Because then we have $Var(X_t) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}$ which is independent from $t$. 
My question is, what is the technical term for choosing $X_0$ in such a way. I only know the german term which is "eingeschwungene Lösung".

Answer (score 2):

> I only know the german term which is "eingeschwungene Lösung".

In English one often uses the [stationary distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_distribution).

It may also refer to [limiting distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_distributions) and possibly in other contexts it could be used as [steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state), but that is another (non-statistics) story.

Comment: Thanks! I think "stationary distribution" comes closest since the AR model can be seen as a Markov chain.

Comment: @Red yes stationary distribution comes closest and that's why I had set it appart. Btw. it can also be considered as the 'marginal distribution', in the viewpoint that the time series follows a multivariate distribution.